# How to iterate over all the YAML values in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand nested maps in Golang. I have a map like below, how do I iterate over all the keys?

```
Data:
  - name: "foo"
    bar1: 0
      k1: val1
      k2:
         val2
         val3
    bar2: 1
      k3: val4
      k4: val5
      k3: val4
      k4: val5
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what the Go structs should look like? If not, can you include them in your question?

Comment: yes, I was having trouble with the go structs . I was trying the below logic

type Config struct {
        foo           map[string]string
        k1      map[string]string
        k2 []map[string]string
} 
if k2 had again a nested value it was failing. something like 
k2:
  val2:
     - val2.1
      - val2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to unmarshal the data into a map `(map[interface{}]interface{}`  or `map[string]interface{})` and then you have to check the type of the values for the keys. You may use the `yaml.v2` package and there might be cleaner interfaces which helps to detect the type of the values. Otherwise check the example that iterates over the keys and print the values:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

var data = `
Data:
    - name: "foo"
      bar1: 0
      k1: val1
      k2:
         val2
         val3
      bar2: 1
      k3: val4
      k4: val5
      k5: val5
      k6: val6
`

func printVal(v interface{}, depth int) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind()
    if typ == reflect.Int || typ == reflect.String {
        fmt.Printf("%s%v\n", strings.Repeat(" ", depth), v)
    } else if typ == reflect.Slice {
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        printSlice(v.([]interface{}), depth+1)
    } else if typ == reflect.Map {
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        printMap(v.(map[interface{}]interface{}), depth+1)
    }

}

func printMap(m map[interface{}]interface{}, depth int) {
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("%sKey:%s", strings.Repeat(" ", depth), k.(string))
        printVal(v, depth+1)
    }
}

func printSlice(slc []interface{}, depth int) {
    for _, v := range slc {
        printVal(v, depth+1)
    }
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("Key:%s ", k)
        printVal(v, 1)
    }
}
```